SSL ignore that the clients certificate is self signed
I'm trying to build a library to build a library to make gemini (the protocol) servers and I got everything working so far except one thing.
In the gemini spec it says that clients are able to send their certificats with tls for identification and such, however when in python I receive the certificate I get an error about how it's self signed  ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1000).
This is how i have my context set up.
...
self.context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
self.context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)

ssl.context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL # optional because the spec says clients don't have to
...

For now I mitigated the problem by loading the clients certificate with .load_verify_locations but that obviously wont work when you would actually run a server publicly.
I expected for it to not even check if the clients certificate is self signed, but it does so you would then expect to be able to turn it off but it seems like I can't? I have read so much of the python SSL documentation and still haven't been able to figure it out.

If a client accepts a self-signed certificate without knowing the verification key in advance, it is trivially vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack

The way to do this with OpenSSL (which is used by Python) would be to install your own verification callback and to accept arbitrary certificates there (to hopefully properly validate them later). Unfortunately this functionality is not exposed through python ssl library. Apart from that: a certificate which you don't validate should not be used for authentication in the first place, since the client could claim anything here.

It's not clear to me if you've trusted the self signed client cert in the truststore at the server, which I presume generates the error.

The clients certificate is not meant to add more security, it's purely meant for identification as far as I understand it. I do want it to be checked that they truly own that key pair however I don't care if its self signed and I'm not quite sure how to fix it caring about it being self signed.
